# How to find shortest distance between two skew lines in 3D?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, 3d

If given 2 lines $\alpha$ and $\beta$, <s>that are created by</s>

1. 2 points: A and B
2. 2 plane intersection

I want to find shortest distance between them.

$$\left\{\begin{array}{c} P_1=x_1X+y_1Y+z_1Z+C=0 \\ P_2=x_2X+y_2Y+z_2Z+C=0\end{array}\right.$$
$$A=\left(x_3;y_3;z_3\right)$$
$$B=\left(x_4;y_4;z_4\right)$$
$$\alpha =n_1\times n_2=\left(\left|\begin{array}{cc} y_1 & z_1 \\ y_2 & z_2\end{array}\right|;-\left|\begin{array}{cc} x_1 & z_1 \\ x_2 & z_2\end{array}\right|;\left|\begin{array}{cc} x_1 & y_1 \\ x_2 & y_2\end{array}\right|\right)$$
$$\beta =$$

From here I tried:

> The question of "shortest distance" is
>   only interesting in the skew case.
>   Let's say $p_0$ and $p_1$ are points on the
>   lines $L_0$ and $L_1$, respectively. Also $d_0$
>   and $d_1$ are the direction vectors of $L_0$
>   and $L_1$, respectively. The shortest
>   distance is $(p_0 - p_1)$ * , in which *
>   is dot product, and is the normalized
>   cross product. The point on $L_0$ that is
>   nearest to $L_1$ is $p_0 + d_0(((p_1 - p_0) *
>  k) / (d_0 * k))$, in which $k$ is $d_1 \times d_0 \times d_1$.

Read more: http://wiki.answers.com/Q/If_the_shortest_distance_between_two_points_is_a_straight_line_what_is_the_shortest_distance_between_two_straight_lines#ixzz17fAWKFst

I tried, but failed.

Comment: What do you mean 2 planes intersection?  If two planes intersect in $\mathbb{R}^3$ they can only create a line.

Comment: @JBeardz Sorry, I made this unclear ... It is totally unimportant. I'm looking for a way to find shortest distance of 2 lines in 3D.

Comment: The wiki answers page you cite and quote looks to me like a failed copy/paste of something else—the symbols don't make sense to me in the way that they are arranged, suggesting to me that something is missing or out of place.  I think the Wikipedia article to which I link in my answer is probably a better resource.

Comment: @Isaac Yes. I'm now struggling to remember how to find $\vec{X_1}$ in case of planes. It would be most helpful, if you could show that.

Comment: @Margus: Interestingly, I was trying to remember the same thing when I was thinking about my answer.  One way you could try is to pick some arbitrary value of one variable, say $z=0$, and solve the system of the two plane equations with that value to find the corresponding $x$ and $y$ coordinates.

Comment: @Isaac Ty. Problem solved.

Comment: Incidentally, the claim that shortest distance is "only interesting" in the skew case is an odd one. Of course you can define shortest distance between parallel lines, and this is still very useful in applications like e.g. collision detection.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_lines#Distance_between_two_skew_lines), if your lines are $\vec{X}=\vec{X_1}+t\vec{D_1}$ and $\vec{X}=\vec{X_2}+t\vec{D_2}$, the distance between them is $$\left|\frac{\vec{D_1}\times\vec{D_2}}{|\vec{D_1}\times\vec{D_2}|}\cdot(\vec{X_1}-\vec{X_2})\right|.$$

Comment: You will have a problem when $D_1=D_2$

Comment: If $D_1=D_2$, the lines aren't skew.

Answer (score 3):

Say you have two lines $\vec L_1 = \vec X_1 + t\vec D_1$ and $\vec L_2 = \vec X_2 + t\vec D_2$.

Start with $(\vec X_1 - \vec X_2)$, which is a skew (non-perpendicular) segment from one line to the other. The distance from $\vec L_1$ to $\vec L_2$ is the component of $(\vec X_1 - \vec X_2)$ that is perpendicular to the lines $\vec L_1$ and $\vec L_2$. We can find this direction by taking the cross product $(\vec L_1 \times \vec L_2)$. After normalizing by dividing by the norm $|\vec L_1 \times \vec L_2|$, take the dot product with $(\vec X_1 - \vec X_2)$ to find the length of the component.

The distance is therefore 
$$
\left|\frac{\vec{D_1}\times\vec{D_2}}{|\vec{D_1}\times\vec{D_2}|}\cdot(\vec{X_1}-\vec{X_2})\right| = \frac{\left|(\vec{D_1}\times\vec{D_2})\cdot(\vec{X_1}-\vec{X_2})\right|}{|\vec{D_1}\times\vec{D_2}|}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

This is the best (quickest and most intuitive) method I've found so far:

[Quick method to find line of shortest distance for skew lines](http://quickmathintuitions.org/quick-method-to-find-line-of-shortest-distance-for-skew-lines/)

> The idea is to consider the vector linking the two lines ($r, s$) in their generic points and then force the perpendicularity with both lines. (Call the line of shortest distance $t$)
>
> This solution allows us to quickly get three results: The equation of the line of shortest distance between the two skew lines; the intersection point between t and s; the intersection point between t and r.