# How do I plug my coordinates into this equation?

Tags: vectors, 3d

I am trying to follow Isaac's answer here: [How to find shortest distance between two skew lines in 3D?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13734/how-to-find-shortest-distance-between-two-skew-lines-in-3d) but I have no background in maths and can't figure out how to enter my coordinates into the equation

The equation I am trying to use is:

$$\left|\frac{\vec{D}_1\times\vec{D}_2}{|\vec{D}_1\times\vec{D}_2|}\cdot(\vec{X}_1-\vec{X}_2)\right|$$

I have implemented this in Python too:
`intersect = np.linalg.norm(np.dot(np.cross(d1,d2)/np.linalg.norm(np.cross(d1,d2)), (x1-x2))`

I don't know where to start, could someone go through this with me?

Thank you so much.

Comment: What information do you have about your two lines?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have the start and end coordinates for each line. At the moment I am trying to create a vector equation for each line

Comment: You write _“I have the start and end coordinates for each line.”_ Are you dealing with lines, or rather with _segments_ (lines don't have such things as “start" or “end”, but segments do; rather call them extremities)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to write the equation of the line in vector form as

\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{x}(t) = \mathbf{X} + t\mathbf{D}
\end{equation*}

where $\mathbf{X}$ is the vector from the origin to a point on the line and $\mathbf{D}$ is a vector parallel to the line. So consider a line through $(x_{1},y_{1},z_{1})$ and $(x_{2},y_{2},z_{2})$. Then you could take

\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{X}_{1} = x_{1}\hat{\boldsymbol{\imath}} + y_{1}\hat{\boldsymbol{\jmath}} + z_{1}\hat{\boldsymbol{k}}
\end{equation*}

and

\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{D}_{1} = (x_{2}-x_{1})\hat{\boldsymbol{\imath}} + (y_{2}-y_{1})\hat{\boldsymbol{\jmath}} + (z_{2}-z_{1})\hat{\boldsymbol{k}}.
\end{equation*}

so the line through $(x_{1},y_{1},z_{1})$ and $(x_{2},y_{2},z_{2})$ can be represented by the equation

\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{x}_{1}(t) = \mathbf{X}_{1} + t\mathbf{D}_{1}.
\end{equation*}

You can do the same thing with the two points you have on the second line and write its equation as $\mathbf{x}_{2}(t) = \mathbf{X}_{2} + t\mathbf{D}_{2}$.

*Edit*: The vectors $\hat{\boldsymbol{\imath}}$, $\hat{\boldsymbol{\jmath}}$, and $\hat{\boldsymbol{k}}$ are the usual unit vectors in the $x$-, $y$-, and $z$-directions:

\begin{equation*}
\hat{\boldsymbol{\imath}} = \left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\
0\\
0
\end{array}\right),\hspace{1pc} \hat{\boldsymbol{\jmath}} = \left(\begin{array}{c}
0\\
1\\
0
\end{array}\right),\hspace{1pc} \mbox{ and }\hspace{1pc} \hat{\boldsymbol{k}} = \left(\begin{array}{c}
0\\
0\\
1
\end{array}\right).
\end{equation*}

So in other words,

\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{X}_{1} = \left(\begin{array}{c}
x_{1}\\
y_{1}\\
z_{1}
\end{array}\right)\hspace{1pc} \mbox{ and }\hspace{1pc}\mathbf{D}_{1} = \left(\begin{array}{c}
x_{2}-x_{1}\\
y_{2}-y_{1}\\
z_{2}-z_{1}
\end{array}\right).
\end{equation*}

Comment: Thank you very much! I would just like to ask, what are i, j and k? Also, having solved your equations, would I then plug those values into the equation in my question? I apologise for my ignorance

Comment: Check out the edit I just made--hopefully that clarifies some things! Once you have found $\mathbf{X}_{1}$, $\mathbf{X}_{2}$, $\mathbf{D}_{1}$, and $\mathbf{D}_{2}$, then yes, you only need to plug those into the equation. Keep in mind, though, that for vectors $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$, the product $\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{b}$ is the *cross product* and $\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b}$ is the *scalar product* (or *dot product*).

Comment: Thank you very much! You are amazing